# Создать отсортированный по категориям выпадающий список

Tags: django

помогите пожалуйста в решении проблемы. В Django я только постигаю азы, прошу отнестись с пониманием. Итак, суть вопроса:
имеется список КАТЕГОРИЙ статей в отдельной таблице(Category), имеется список статей в другой таблице(Main).
Поле category таблицы Main связано с таблицей Category.
Необходимо вывести список категорий, и под каждым пунктом категории выпадающим списком вывести список статей, привязанных к данной категории.
Примерно так:

```
    КАТЕГОРИЯ-1
        Заголовок1 статьи КАТЕГОРИИ-1
        Заголовок2 статьи КАТЕГОРИИ-1
        Заголовок3 статьи КАТЕГОРИИ-1
    КАТЕГОРИЯ-2
        Заголовок1 статьи КАТЕГОРИИ-2
        Заголовок2 статьи КАТЕГОРИИ-2
        Заголовок3 статьи КАТЕГОРИИ-2
```

То есть должна быть сортировка статей по категориям.
Есть следующий код:

```
models.py
class Main(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=55, db_index=True, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True, help_text="Enter the contents of this page")
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, verbose_name='Категория')
    

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, verbose_name='Категория')


views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Main, Category


def index(request):
    list_cat = Category.objects.all()
    list_main = Main.objects.all()
    context = {"list_cat": list_cat, "list_main": list_main}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
models.py
class Main(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=55, db_index=True, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True, help_text="Enter the contents of this page")
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, verbose_name='Категория')
    

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, verbose_name='Категория')


views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Main, Category


def index(request):
    list_cat = Category.objects.all()
    list_main = Main.objects.all()
    context = {"list_cat": list_cat, "list_main": list_main}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

Часть кода шаблона
index.html:

```
{% for list_cat in list_cat %}    
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#category{{ list_cat.id }}" role="button" aria-expanded="false"
                           aria-controls="collapseExample2">{{ list_cat.title }}</a><br>    Печать списка категорий
                        <div class="collapse ml-2" id="category{{ list_cat.id }}">
                            {% for list_main in list_main %}   
                                {% if list_main.title == list_cat.title %}      Условие совпадения категории и заголовка статьи категории
                                    <p>{{ list_main.title }}</p>   Вывод заголовка статьи ДАННОЙ категории
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
```

Такой код html не работает(условие {% if list_main.title == list_cat.title %}почему-то автоматом False.)
Вернее, он выдаёт только список категорий, заголовки статей данной категории не выводятся.
Если применить обходной манёвр введением дополнительного поля keycategory в модель Main таким образом:

```
models.py
class Main(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=55, db_index=True, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True, help_text="Enter the contents of this page")
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, verbose_name='Категория')
    keycategory = models.IntegerField(blank=True, db_index=True, null=True, verbose_name='КлючКатегории')
```

Затем вручную в админке прописать значение поля keycategory равным значению category_id в модели Category и подкорректировать код html вот так:

```
{% for list_cat in list_cat %}    Печать списка категорий
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#category{{ list_cat.id }}" role="button" aria-expanded="false"
                           aria-controls="collapseExample2">{{ list_cat.title }}</a><br>
                        <div class="collapse ml-2" id="category{{ list_cat.id }}">
                            {% for list_main in list_main %}   
                                {% if list_main.keycategory == list_cat.id %}   Условие совпадения категории и заголовка статьи категории
                                    <p>{{ list_main.title }}</p>   Вывод заголовка статьи ДАННОЙ категории
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
```

То сказочным образом всё начинает работать. Я получаю действительно отсортированные по категориям выпадающие списки.
Но такой путь, конечно, не Путь Самурая.
Собственно вопрос в чём:
Почему условие **{% if list_main.keycategory == list_cat.id %}**,то есть сравнение полей IntegerField Django воспринимает адекватно и не ругается,
а в случае **{% if list_main.title == list_cat.title %}**,то есть сравнение полей CharField - полный игнор с его стороны? Может возможен ещё
какой-нибудь финт, чтобы уговорить Django сравнить символьные поля?
Разъясните, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Не мучайте себя и джанго

```
#views.py
categories = Category.objects.filter(...).order_by('title', 'main__title')
...



# *.html

{% for cat in categories %}
    {{ cat.title }}
    {% for article in cat.main_set.all %}
        {{ article.title }} from {{ article.category.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Если укажите у поля category в Main `related_name`, по сможете обращаться из модели `Category` по этому имени

Для сортировки связанных объектов, и оптимизации выборки, читать [prefetch_related](https://django.fun/tutorials/select_related-i-prefetch_related-v-django/) и [Prefetch](https://smyt.ru/blog/django-orm/)